# Creating objects with random inputs

Tags: java

I have created a simple algorithm to solve a bin packing problem. To test it properly I need to create lots of box objects of various sizes (different lengths and widths). I have a box object: `public Box(int width, int height)` How would I create say 500 boxes without hard coding them of different sizes and store them in an `ArrayList`?

Thank you for your help

Comment: what are the min value and max value of  width and higth?

Comment: I've set the max width a box can have to 250 and the max height to 200.

Comment: try the answer that you have this is what I wanted to let you know and check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Random` class, perhaps with a factory method:

```
public static Box create(int minWidth, int maxWidth, int minHeight, int maxHeight) {
    Random random = Random();
    return new Box(minWidth + random.nextInt(maxWidth - minWidth), minHeight+ random.nextInt(maxHeight - minHeight));
}
```